# How can I pass through timezone as a connection string parameter to change the users session tz

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I know you can do it with the JDBC driver as snowflake says;

"Any session parameter can be included in the connection string. For example:
CLIENT_SESSION_KEEP_ALIVE=true"

So could do TIMEZONE=UTC

but how can I do this through the odbc driver connection string or how could I achieve this goal using an odbc connection string parameter, would it be possible to call a stored procedure from the connection string that would then set the timezone for that user's session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still add the TIMEZONE parameter for ODBC in /etc/odbc.ini for Linux or for Windows in registry.

```
/etc/odbc.ini

timezone=UTC
```

Once connected you can check the value of timezone  by:

```
show parameters like 'TIMEZONE' in session;
```

Should report UTC.

Comment: Just to answer my own question. This was for a MicroStrategy connection to snowflake, using a DB connection object. Passing in the "Additional connection string parameters", it worked.

driver={SnowflakeDSIIDriver};server=XXX.snowflakecomputing.com;port=443;database=XXX_DB;warehouse=XXX_WH;schema=XXX_EN;timezone=US/Mountain;